# How to create a folder as a normal user in Oracle 10G

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

This is what I have tried so far. It's creating the folder when I run this script as a sysdba user. But, I want to create the folder as a normal user. I have given all the appropriate grants.

```
Declare
 my_Directory varchar2(100);

Begin

MY_DIRECTORY := 'C:\TEST';

DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
job_name =>'create_directory',
JOB_TYPE =>'executable',
job_action => 'c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c mkdir C:\TEST',
enabled =>true,
auto_drop => true
);
commit;
END;
/
```

I'm using Windows XP.

Comment: What actually happens? Do you get an error? Is it creating a folder but not owned by the Windows user you expect?

Comment: There are no errors, but the required folder is not getting created.

Comment: There should be an error somewhere; the user might not see one if the job is created successfully, but if the job execution fails it will be visible from OEM, or possibly in the alert log.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to query dba_scheduler_job_run_details and dba_scheduler_job_log to get a better idea of what happened when the job ran.  I'm pretty sure you'll find a grant is missing for that user.

Answer (score 0):

Login as SYSDBA and give the following grants to your user/usergroup

```
GRANT CREATE job, CREATE EXTERNAL job TO YOUR_USER;
```

now you can run your plsql block with YOUR_USER.